# How To Move Files With Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to move files with batch file and thats work but ı don't wanna move files inside the appdata. How can I skip AppData files.

```
@ECHO OFF
Robocopy C:\Users\%User%\ C:\NewFolder\ /E /MOV
EXIT
```

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `robocopy /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, to read its usage information. Pay particular attention to the exclude options. If there is a reason why those are not suitable for you, please [edit] your question to explain the reason why.

Comment: Curios as to what was stopping you from reading the help file for `Robocopy`? It clearly has an option to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this :)

```
Robocopy C:\Users\%User%\ C:\NewFolder\ /E /Z /ZB /R:5 /W:5 /TBD /V /XD C:\Users\%User%\AppData
```

> Here are the subcommands I've used
> /E — Copy Subdirectories, including empty ones.
> /Z — Copy files in restartable mode.
> /ZB — Uses restartable mode, if access denied use backup mode.
> /R:5 — Retry 5 times (you can specify a different number, default is 1 million).
> /W:5 — Wait 5 seconds before retrying (you can specify a different number, default is 30 seconds).
> /TBD — Wait for sharenames To Be Defined (retry error 67).
> /V — Produce verbose output, showing skipped files.
> /XD — Excludes folders matching the path and folder name

Comment: @TallisChromo please remember to accept the answer